# Redis master/slave how to rewrite content of master to slave

Tags: c#, redis, master-slave

I have two Redis database configured as master/slave.

I added keys to slave. How to rewrite content of slave to master ?
When I add key to master it is only i master Redis. And when I add key to slave it is only in slave Redis.
How to get key from master in slave? And vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis' master/slave replication is strictly one way, from the master to the slave(s). Any updates to the master are replicated downstream and overwrite the slave's contents.

If your replication is runnnng, all master updates will be replicated almost immediately to the slave. If you use writable slaves, keys that exist in both master and slave will be overwritten by the master's replication stream. New keys that exist only in the slave (when writable) will never be replicated upstream to the master. The only way to add keys to the master is by writing directly to it (or if it is itself a replica, then to its master...).

The question remaining is why would you want to write keys to the slave and have them shipped to the master as well. You could, theoretically, have your application write to both master and slave but I shiver thinking about the race conditions and consistency issues that you'll run into if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing would be a multi-master setup, which is not possible with Redis.

Comment: Impossible currently but perhaps sometime... There have been some talk lately on what it would take to make this happen - very exciting stuff :)